# xhprof displaying empty run

Tags: php, drupal-7, xhprof

I'm trying to profile a drupal website using `xhprof`. I manage to install it and configure drupal to use it (using the devel module) but I have a problem to visualize the result.

First, for some reason I didn't manage to get the access rights to xhprof_html through apache. Instead of using apache I just cd into xhprof_html directory and run `php -S myhost:8080`. I can then see the main page with all the runs, but when I select a run, it's empty. I can see the table and everything but there is no functions displayed. When I look at the run with a text editor it seems ok.

What am I doing wrong ? Is there another tool to visualize xhprof runs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. My site name includes an `&` which generates file name to readable by the XHProf.